# Pasting Flipped Animation Dope Sheet

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I am following a tutorial on how to make a walking animation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=548&v=gFf5eGCjUUg&feature=emb_logo) and at 8:52, it says in the dope sheet to press shift-control-V to paste the animation flipped. Whenever I do this it only does it for the spine and head and not the arms or legs. I named all the bones appropriately (RightHand and LeftHand or RightArmIK and LeftArmIK) but still whenever I try to paste the flipped animation it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Doesn't paste anything that says left and right

Answer (score 0):

So I went and renamed all the bones to .R or .L and it worked then so I guess right and left don't work in the dope sheet.